# failed to authenticate to <ip> | adb wifi

Tags: android, wifi, adb, wireless

When connecting a device with ADB Wireless,
got `failed to authenticate to <ip>`

`adb devices` gives the device shows up as unauthorized.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From Android 4.2, every ADB device needs to be authorized for a computer to connect. This is done for security. So when a USB is connected a prompt comes asking to authorize the device when USB debugging is set. But does not happen for WIFI ADB.

So the workaround is to connect the device by USB, accepting the machine always. Then when the Wireless ADB is tried, it should work.

Comment: What to do when device doesn't prompt you to authorize?

Comment: What is your Android version? Have you enabled USB debugging or any other kind of developer mode? More details please.

Comment: Android 4.4.2.  Yes, USB debugging was enabled.  And I found the fix referenced in another StackOverflow post: 
uncheck then re-check USB debugging

Answer (score 13):

**Solution**

1 Connect device(over USB) to computer (WINDOWS).

2 Authorize adb device, so it can communicate(handshake over USB) with computer

3 Check that the device is connected

```
$adb devices

List of devices attached

SC8SDQWGKBT4JVS4        device
```

4 Change to tcpip mode

```
$adb tcpip 5555

restarting in TCP mode port: 5555
```

5 Connect device(over WIFI) to computer, make sure both are on the same network

```
$adb connect 192.168.1.100

connected to 192.168.1.100:5555
```

6 Authorize adb device, so it can communicate(handshake over WIFI) with computer

7 Check that the device is connected

```
$adb devices

List of devices attached

SC8SDQWGKBT4JVS4        device

192.168.1.100:5555      unauthorized
```

> Although I authorized the device, adb is seeing things differently.
>
> To get things working correctly, unplug device from USB because there
>   is a connection over WIFI.

8 Kill the adb server

```
$adb kill-server
```

9 Connect again over WIFI

```
$adb connect 192.168.1.100

* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *

* daemon started successfully *

connected to 192.168.1.100:5555
```

10 Finally, Check that the device is connect

```
$adb devices

List of devices attached

192.168.1.100:5555      device
```

> Device is now authorized, you can start debugging over WIFI.

Comment: i had to do SUDO adb connect IP_ADDRESS in linux, then it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use the ADB WiFi([an Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ryosoftware.adbw)).I use it and the device showed in the Android studio is authorized(Forget to tell,I use USB connect to the Mac ,then the phone will promote a dialog to authorize the mac to debug the phone).

Answer (score 0):

In the {} Developer options menu item, Revoke USB debugging authorizations, and then disable and enable the USB debugging option to get dialog.

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2024 (using FireTVStick lite), invoking: `adb connect <ip>` prompts authorization message on the Fire TV and you don't need to use USB as workaround. Once accepting it on the TV the wifi can be used directly to connect without any need of USB.
Cheers