# How do I setup Android Continuous Integration on a VM?

Tags: android, continuous-integration, virtual-machine, xen

I'm creating an Android project. For CI, I am using Bamboo but can easily switch to Jenkins. That CI system lives on a VM via Xen, which cannot be easily changed. I have no problem running the Java Unit tests, but when I try to run the Android unit tests, I need either an emulator or a device. But

- The emulator will not run on Xen because that would create a VM-within-a-VM issue ([See S/O question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729150/is-it-possible-to-run-android-device-emulator-via-android-studio-2-on-vmware))
- A device cannot connect over USB (`adb usb`) to the VM because Xen cannot forward USB devices to guests ([See S/O question](https://serverfault.com/questions/815242/usb-passthrough-non-storage-to-xenserver-7-vm))
- A device cannot connect over wifi (`adb tcpip; adb connect`) because it needs it is marked as Unauthorized. Authorization is only granted via USB. [See S/O question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485467/adb-wireless-device-unauthorized)

Can anyone think of a workaround? Routing USB in Xen, running the emulator in Xen, or authorizing the CI computer to use the device would work. The only thing I can think of is to have additional dedicated hardware which is not a great solution for me.

Comment: Eventhough it is expensive, I would like to throw in some options https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/pricing/

Comment: That's not a bad idea. Also, someone verbally had the idea to create a VM using virtualbox (for example because it supports USB) then exporting/importing it to Xen. Downsides are that a) it's time consuming and b) the process needs to be repeated if USB auth is lost or if a new device is added.

Comment: I would suggest you to have a look at packer and vagrant. With packer you can create a box with all required software and with vagrant you can reuse that box anywhere. You don't have to "repeat" the steps !! Works great too